# Linearly interpolating Pandas Time Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am pulling data on exchange rates using `Pandas`. The data does not have values for every single day. I'd like to fill in the missing time series using `Pandas` `interoplate` function so that all dates are included in the index. For example, 2010-01-09 and 2010-01-10 are both missing. The `interoplate` function seems not to be doing anything, but I can't figure out why.

```
from pandas_datareader import data

can = data.get_data_fred('DEXCAUS')
can = can.interpolate(method='linear')
can = can.dropna()
print can.head(10)
```

Output:

```
            DEXCAUS
DATE               
2010-01-04   1.0377
2010-01-05   1.0371
2010-01-06   1.0333
2010-01-07   1.0351
2010-01-08   1.0345
2010-01-11   1.0317
2010-01-12   1.0374
2010-01-13   1.0319
2010-01-14   1.0260
2010-01-15   1.0287
```

Desired Output:

```
            DEXCAUS
DATE               
2010-01-04   1.0377
2010-01-05   1.0371
2010-01-06   1.0333
2010-01-07   1.0351
2010-01-08   1.0345
2010-01-09   some value..
2010-01-10   some value..
2010-01-11   1.0317
2010-01-12   1.0374
2010-01-13   1.0319
2010-01-14   1.0260
2010-01-15   1.0287
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resample first:

```
df.resample('D').interpolate(method='linear')
Out: 
             DEXCAUS
DATE                
2010-01-04  1.037700
2010-01-05  1.037100
2010-01-06  1.033300
2010-01-07  1.035100
2010-01-08  1.034500
2010-01-09  1.033567
2010-01-10  1.032633
2010-01-11  1.031700
2010-01-12  1.037400
2010-01-13  1.031900
2010-01-14  1.026000
2010-01-15  1.028700
```